# How do i fix the error 'The command line is too long' if i want to have the output from a command?

Tags: perl, pipeline

I have a perl code with a very long command and I want print the output to a log file. It looks like this:

```
system ( "$cmd  | tee -a $log_file" );
```

When I run the Perl script, the system call throws "The command line is too long".

If I run the system call without pipeline, it works.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a limit of characters for pipeline?
2. How can I fix the problem?

Some additional informations:

The command `$cmd` has a length of 8532. I am using Perl version 5.003_07 (yes, i know it's old. My company is the owner.).

Comment: Hi, what operating system? Have you tried running the command at the command prompt? Both with and without pipeline of course.

Comment: 5.003_07 was released on Oct 10th, 1996!!! The average person of the time had never heard of the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a positively ancient version of Perl. The first one I used was 5.004 in the mid-90s. Granted, things may have changed, but I think that the following quotation from the `system()` documentation is still relevant.

> If there is only one scalar argument, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (this is "/bin/sh -c" on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms). If there are no shell metacharacters in the argument, it is split into words and passed directly to "execvp", which is more efficient.

It seems likely that you are experiencing the difference between these two cases, and that the (external) shell program is imposing the length limit when you add the pipe.

You could work around this by temporarily re-opening STDOUT as "| tee -a $log_file", then just executing `system($cmd)`. I daren't try to tell you how exactly to do that (particularly if you want to get your old STDOUT back afterwards) under such an ancient version of Perl, because that most certainly has changed over time. You'll need to consult the documentation at hand.

One possibility is to `fork()`, then in the child process `open STDOUT, "| tee -a $log_file"`, and `exec($cmd)`, and in the parent process `wait()` for all that to finish, bearing in mind that there is more than one child process because you opened a pipe.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm not sure what "tee" would make of a situation where STDOUT was a pipe to itself. The universe might explode.

Comment: Well, I just tried this, the desired effect was achieved, and the universe is still here. perl -we 'open STDOUT, "|tee /tmp/foo" or die "$!\n"; system("ls")'

Comment: Glad that risk panned out on all our behalves.

Comment: If I'm going to do something that might explode the universe, I figure it's easier to get forgiveness than permission.

Comment: @TFBW It works with open ( STDOUT... and system($cmd) as you mentioned. Thank you very much. It can be marked as solved.